# Plugin Code - What does it mean?

Tags: php, plugins

I installed lucia's linky love on my site and comments are showing up as (new comment) instead of showing the count. I don't even know what that means. How do I make it show the actual count and what does "new comment" mean?

I know this text is included but don't understand it:

```
if (($oldCommentDate <  mysql2date('U', $comment->comment_date)) ||  $daysBefore < -14 ||!$sameNameExclude ){
   //echo('<br>This is new  or 14 days after last post or excluded name: return ');
   if( is_user_logged_in() )
    $text .= " (new comment) ";
   return $text;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like if the comment is less than 14 days old it shows `(new comment)` by the text.